# Windows 10 File Version History, real-time backup/copy-on-write

Tags: windows-10, backup, ntfs, history

I understand that Windows 10 File Version History feature does incremental backups at fixed schedule (every 10mins to 24hrs). And that it checks the NTFS '[Change Journals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx)'

However, is it possible to trigger Windows 10 File Version History to backup as soon as the file is changed, rather than waiting for the next scheduled time?
[image: Windows 10 Control Panel File Version History Advanced Settings]

Thanks,

Comment: No;  Sounds like you want third-party software. To be specific, third-party software can implement VSS but in the implementation MS used for this feature it’s limited to every 10 minutes

Comment: @Ramhound so, not even a command prompt to trigger backup now? Or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically found one half of the solution, to trigger Windows File Version History to backup now.

I just need to run this command on command line `fhmanagew.exe -backupnow`, this should get File Version History to backup on demand. Thanks to: [Adam's Code Blog](http://blog.bitcollectors.com/adam/2017/07/file-history-command-line-tool/)

However, I still need to find a way to monitor the NTFS Change Journals, to get the above command to trigger.

P.S: This seems to be a solution theoretically, yet to see this in action.

Feel free to post any solutions.